# converting bootstrap template into next js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-4

i am trying to convert bootstrap template into next js which is using owl.carousel.js library its only showing image in carousel for like 1 sec
reference video => https://streamable.com/h0c9o2
github => https://github.com/AnonymousDEV001/nextJs-carasol

in github code its just carousel so u don't waste your time finding the right page

I had hydration issue i fixed that and now i don't have any errors and now its not showing carousel image at all not even for a sec

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)